# Express res.send or res.json doesn't contain a body

Tags: express

I'm calling an API to fetch orders for a given user based on ID which are fetched from a third-party site. These are fetched correctly as a console.log them in the node server. But when I try to send the results back to the client neither res.send nor res.json results sending the data back to the client. Here is an example of an order from console.log:

```
{"customer":{"orders":{"edges":[{"node":{"id":"gid://shopify/Order/1234564564","lineItems":{"edges":[{"node":{"title":"Some title here"}}]}}}]}}}
```

Then on the client in the devtools when I console.log the response I get:

```
body:ReadableStream
  locked:false
  [[Prototype]]:ReadableStream
bodyUsed:false
headers: 
   Headers {}
ok:true
redirected:false
status:200
statusText:"OK"
type:"basic"
url:"http://localhost:9000/api/getOrders?cid=gid://shopify/Customer/1234564564"
[[Prototype]]:Response
```

Any help is appreciated.

**=== UPDATE ===**

I've now even tried the most basic of examples and am getting the same response on the client:

```
app.get('/testExpress', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello")
});
```

Thanks to @laurent here is how I was able to receive that response on the client:

```
fetch('/testExpress')
  .then(async (r) => {
    const resp = await r.text();
    console.log(resp);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to get the json out of the response by `const json = await response.json()`.

These are the available methods to parse the response body depending on what you want:

Response.arrayBuffer()
Returns a promise that resolves with an ArrayBuffer representation of the response body.

Response.blob()
Returns a promise that resolves with a Blob representation of the response body.

Response.clone()
Creates a clone of a Response object.

Response.formData()
Returns a promise that resolves with a FormData representation of the response body.

Response.json()
Returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.

Response.text()
Returns a promise that resolves with a text representation of the response body.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response

The Response object is a representation of the http response. You should try to receive the body of the response by using one of these methods or parsing the body from the readable stream `response.body`.

Comment: Holy crap that worked, driving me crazy - thank you.

`fetch('/testExpress')
  .then(async (r) => {
    const resp = await r.text();
    console.log(resp);
  })`